# Actionscript Graph data structure implementation

Tags: graph, actionscript-3, actionscript

So, I am not sure if I should have `Vertex` *extend* `Point`, because the `equals()` and `compareTo()` functions are already parameterized with `Point`. I guess I don't really need compare to...

Does this structure look good? I used a `Map` instead of a `TreeMap` because as3commons and the default flex packages do not have this structure defined. How easy will this be if I were to create it.

Things that I am in the process of working out now:

- I know I need to add `removeVertex()` (and `removeEdge()`?)
- If I want to create an `Edge` class, I supposed I would make the following changes:

  ```
  // Since this is undirected, do I need 2 edges, because I have src and dest?
  public class Edge {
      public var src:Vertex;
      public var dest:Vertex;
      public var data:Object;

      public function Edge(src:Vertex, dest:Vertex, data:Object=null) {
          // Set instance variables
      }
  }

  public class Graph {
      public var edges:IMap; // <Object, Edge>

      public function addEdge(from:Object, to:Object, data:Object):void {
          edges.add(data, new Edge(v, w));
      }
  }
  ```

My main gripe would be about juggling all of these data types.

- `public var adjList:IMap; // <Vertex, Set>`
- `public var vertices:IMap; // <Object, Vertex>`
- `public var edges:IMap; // <Object, Edge>`

This may make if difficult to intelligently traverse the graph.

---

### Reference classes and files:

**Vertex.as**

```
package core {
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Vertex extends Point {
        public var data:Object;

        public function Vertex(data:Object=null, x:Number=0, y:Number=0) {
            super(x, y);

            this.data = data;
        }

        // Implement...
        override public function clone():Point {
            return new Vertex(data, x, y);
        }

        override public function toString():String { 
            return data.toString();
        }

        // Implement...
        override public function equals(toCompare:Point):Boolean {
            return super.equals(toCompare) && this.compareTo(toCompare as Vertex) == 0;
        }

        // Implement...
        public function compareTo(other:Vertex):int {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Graph.as**

```
package core {
    import org.as3commons.collections.Map;
    import org.as3commons.collections.Set;
    import org.as3commons.collections.framework.IMap;
    import org.as3commons.collections.framework.ISet;

    public class Graph {
        public var adjList:IMap; // <Vertex, Set>
        public var vertices:IMap; // <Object, Vertex>

        private static const EMPTY_SET:ISet = new Set();

        private var _numVertices:int;
        private var _numEdges:int;

        public function Graph() {
            adjList = new Map();
            vertices = new Map();
            _numVertices = _numEdges = 0;
        }

        public function addVertex(data:Object):Vertex {
            var v:Vertex = vertices.itemFor(data);

            if (v == null) {
                v = new Vertex(data);
                vertices.add(data, v);
                adjList.add(v, new Set());
                _numVertices++;
            }

            return v;
        }

        public function getVertex(data:Object):Vertex {
            return vertices.itemFor(data);
        }

        public function hasVertex(data:Object):Boolean {
            return vertices.hasKey(data);
        }

        public function hasEdge(from:Object, to:Object):Boolean {
            if (!hasVertex(from) || !hasVertex(to))
                return false;
            return (adjList.itemFor(vertices.itemFor(from)) as Set).has(vertices.itemFor(to));
        }

        public function addEdge(from:Object, to:Object):void {
            var v:Vertex, w:Vertex;
            if (hasEdge(from, to))
                return;
            _numEdges += 1;
            if ((v = getVertex(from)) == null)
                v = addVertex(from);
            if ((w = getVertex(to)) == null)
                w = addVertex(to);
            (adjList.itemFor(v) as Set).add(w);
            (adjList.itemFor(w) as Set).add(v);
        }

        public function adjacentTo(value:*):ISet {
            if (value is Object && hasVertex(value as Object)) {
                return adjList.itemFor(getVertex(value as Object)) as Set;
            }

            if (value is Vertex && adjList.has(value as Vertex)) {
                return adjList.itemFor(value as Vertex) as Set;
            }

            return EMPTY_SET;
        }

        public function getVertices():ISet {
            var set:ISet = new Set();
            for each (var v:Vertex in vertices.toArray()) {
                set.add(v);
            }
            return set;
        }

        public function numVertices():int {
            return _numVertices;
        }

        public function numEdges():int {
            return _numEdges;
        }

        public function toString():String {
            var s:String = "";
            for each (var v:Vertex in vertices.toArray()) {
                s += v + ": ";

                var set:ISet = adjList.itemFor(v) as Set;
                for each (var w:Vertex in set.toArray()) {
                    s += (w + " ");
                }
                s += "\n";
            }
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

**App.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    creationComplete="onComplete(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import core.Graph;
            import core.Vertex;

            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function onComplete(event:FlexEvent):void {
                main();
            }

            public static function main(args:Vector.<String>=null):void {
                var G:Graph = new Graph();

                G.addEdge("A", "B");
                G.addEdge("A", "C");
                G.addEdge("C", "D");
                G.addEdge("D", "E");
                G.addEdge("D", "G");
                G.addEdge("E", "G");
                G.addVertex("H");
                // print out graph
                trace(G);

                trace('Verticies:', G.numVertices());
                trace('Edges    :', G.numEdges());
                trace();

                // print out graph again by iterating over vertices and edges
                for each (var v:Vertex in G.getVertices().toArray()) {
                    var str:String = v + ": ";
                    for each (var w:Vertex in G.adjacentTo(v.data).toArray()) {
                        str += w + " ";
                    }
                    trace(str);
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: After doing some research, I found that the best answer for this question: [SO: How do I properly extend the AS3 Point class?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9015761/1762224) states that the point class should be a delegate of the class that, in theory, **extends** it.

Comment: Typically graphs are represented by adjacency table. This would save you some place, and would be less surprising for the reader. This also makes `Edge` class unnecessary. You would be only storing vertices. But this may depend on your use case. For graphs with labeled edges it might make sense to actually create such a class, or maybe to extend the adjacency table to have triples rather than tuples.

Answer (score 2):

`adjList` needs a more descriptive name. Specifically as a class member variable, it deserves the few extra characters it would take to be called `adjacencyList`.

Additionally, you have extended `Point`, but do not use any of `Point`'s functions. Does Point even provide functions? (Yes, it does.)

I'd have gone with a `Vertex` class that contains a `Point`, not `extends` it. You pointed this out yourself in a comment as well.

---

```
    public function adjacentTo(value:*):ISet {
        if (value is Object && hasVertex(value as Object)) {
            return adjList.itemFor(getVertex(value as Object)) as Set;
        }

        if (value is Vertex && adjList.has(value as Vertex)) {
            return adjList.itemFor(value as Vertex) as Set;
        }

        return EMPTY_SET;
    }
```

This is a nasty bit of code. I wanted to say that you should swap the two checks, as any `Vertex` is also an `Object`, and you end up always checking if any of your vertices has `value` as `data`. But if you were to have a `Vertex` which has another `Vertex` as `data` then swapping the two would make the function fail to perform properly. A comment along these lines would go a long way towards not shooting yourself in the foot later.

```
    public function addVertex(data:Object):Vertex {
        var v:Vertex = vertices.itemFor(data);
        //codes
    }

    public function getVertex(data:Object):Vertex {
        return vertices.itemFor(data);
    }
```

Reuse your functions where you can; like that you allow code to be read at a semantic level, rather than a syntactical level. Logical reasoning likes to work with semantics and not bother so much with the syntax. In this case, you can reuse `getVertex`:

```
    public function addVertex(data:Object):Vertex {
        var v:Vertex = getVertex(data);
        //codes
    }
```

Comment: `adjList` == Adjacency List

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl rephrased the sentence and expanded a bit